# Json and datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, local-storage

I have to create a datatable with a script, using a JSON object previously saved in `localStorage` (this part works). Therefore, I cannot use Ajax I suppose.

this is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var dataSet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contact Info"));
      alert (dataSet.firstName);//to check if data are correctly parsed
    $("#table1").dataTable({

data: dataSet,
       columns:[
        {data: "name" },
        {data: "lastName" },
        {data: "phone"},
        {data: "email"},
        {data: "city"},
      ]
    });
  });
});
```

but it does not work (no error messages, just it does not populate my datatable). 
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe throw up a jsfiddle with test data

Comment: There's an extra comma after the last item in `columns`: `{data: "city"},` <-- Removing that might fix it?

Comment: It did not, I am working on it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Okay, I solved the issue... my variable was not an array. Thank you all.